# How to set MongoDB driver on XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, xampp

I try to set `MongoDB on XAMPP`, but don't work :(

I use

**Windows 10**,

**XAMPP v3.2.1**

**PHP 5.6.8**

Which driver I need to download? Thanks to all!! :)

XAMPP INFO: http://oi62.tinypic.com/294qk4k.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to setup MongoDB in xampp.

[Configure MongoDB with PHP on windows for XAMPP in 5 simple steps](http://devzone.co.in/configure-mongodb-php-windows-xampp-5-simple-steps/)

Also after setting up ,cross check your PHP configuration for following:

Removing the ; from the beginning of

```
;extension=php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9.dll
```

in your php.ini to enable MongoDB.

Also set extension_dir as absolute path in php.ini

```
extension_dir = "d:\php-5.4.32\ext"
```

comment the php_curl.dll module in php.ini

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i follow this tutorial but don't work..
I try all .dll files..

Comment: Don't work, i follow all step:
Copy driver .dll into ext folder and add extension on php.ini

Comment: From where you have downloaded the driver and which version

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html
I have used: php_mongo-1.6.8.zip

Comment: what version of mongo you have install in windows? Have you restarted your server?

Comment: [12-Jun-2015 11:22:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0

[12-Jun-2015 11:22:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0

Comment: can you re post the php configuration?

Comment: ok php.ini con figuration looks fine , can you tell which .dll compatibnle file you have put on to ext folder ?

Comment: i have try all .dll file

Comment: Try to uninstall all and reinstall,xampp and mongo ,see if it  is work.

Comment: I have follow the http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/#PHPLanguageCenter-Windows tutorial and it's working fine on my windows 8 pc. There must me somthing you were missing.

Comment: Given link is broken

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you still need another answer but I guess, I had a similar problem.

I've downloaded the right php_mongodb.dll for my configuration (xampp with PHP 5.6.24, MSVC11, x86 and thread safety enabled) and tried to set up the configuration many times without any changes.

So, I've tried a new php version (xampp with PHP 7.0.18, MSVC14, x86 and thread safety enabled) and I've got all what I've wanted in 5 mins.